# Spring mvc persist data when dijit dialog is closed

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo

I have a create view where the user and fill some data and if they click on a button a dijit.dialog opens with a list of items to select. Everything works fine, except that when the dialog confirms the selected items it goes to the controller to do some logic and refreshes the create view deleting the data that the user filled previously.

How can I make the dialog persist what the user already filled (maybe going to the controller to set the data before opening it)? Or maybe try to close the dialog, refresh the list that I show on the dialog and part of the create view that uses what the user selected.

Not sure if I make myself clear enough.

**Edit**

My project is based on Spring Roo:

```
<form:create .....>
 .. inputs and tables ..
  <input type="button" ../> //goes to controller and loads page with dialog open

<tiles:insertTemplate template="/WEB-INF/views/dialog.jspx" />

</form>
```

Dialog code:

```
<div id="dialog" dojoType="dijit.Dialog">
  <form id="items" dojoType="dijit.form.Form">
    <jsp:doBody/>
    <input id="save" type="submit" name="sendDialogData">
  </form>
</div>
```

I thought that would make the dialog part of the form but just checked with firebug and it is created after the "wrapper" (the div that contains everything)

Comment: It sounds like you are not submitting the main form values with the dialog form values.  You may want to show some code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: At first it was on a different form. Now I'm trying to make the dialog part of the same original form but when I see the HTML code it is out of the form.

Comment: If tiles is putting your JSP snippet in the wrong place, you can import the JSP on your own.  However, this seems a tad hokey.  I think the tag is jsp:include.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using JSPX, not JSP. I believe that the problem is that dijit.Dialog creates the dialog at the bottom of the body's code by default. So is impossible to have it on the same form as the rest of the data.

Comment: JSPX just means your JSP is XML parsable.  The import and tiles should be doing what equates to a simple copy of the given file into your file, then evaluating the new contents.  If you do the import/tiles tag in your Form, then you should have the inserted JSPF in that spot.

Comment: Ok. After a while I managed to submit the data into the controller when the user wants to open the dialog and as a result I refresh the whole view but with the dialog open. It takes a few seconds and is not the happiest solution but the user won't notice..

Comment: If you want to avoid the refresh, your best option is AJAX or some messaging framework, like Atmosphere.  You would create an event handler on the dialog (not sure how to do this in dojo, I usually use jQuery) that would fire off the persist event on the dialog's close event.  This service would then persist the entry and reply with some reponse, which you can then display on the view.